# How to separate by comma with csv

Tags: python, csv

I have the list:

```
x=["2018-08-27 15:21:49","2018-08-27 15:21:52","2018-08-27 15:21:56"]
y=["5523","3512","3383"]
```

I want the csv will be like ("" is in one cell)

```
"2018-08-27 15:21:49" "5523"
"2018-08-27 15:21:52" "3512"
```

but the following code could not work. If I don't use the [row], each cell will be filled with one character. I understand that this will be easy, but would you please offer a help? My brain just go blank and could not figure it out...
Thanks!

```
import csv
x=["2018-08-27 15:21:49","2018-08-27 15:21:52","2018-08-27 15:21:56"]
y=["5523","3512","3383"]
L=[]
with open("test.csv","w",newline='') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        row=x[i]+','+y[i]
        print([row])
```

Comment: I think you need `writer.writerow(row)`; currently you just print.

Comment: @Cleb Yes. I have a typo. It should be the writerow(row) but it will separate each character into each cell. Argo have provided an answer. Thanks for the check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. What you need to do is use `writer.writerow` but do make sure that you don't use `row=x[i]+','+y[i]` because it will make it as a single string and it would become a single row rather than 2 rows.

```
import csv
x=["2018-08-27 15:21:49","2018-08-27 15:21:52","2018-08-27 15:21:56"]
y=["5523","3512","3383"]
L=[]
with open("test.csv","w",newline='') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        writer.writerow([x[i], y[i]])
```

**UPDATE:**

When one uses `writer.writerow(row)` then it doesn't work as per desired result because if you see the implemtation of `writerow`

```
def writerow(self, row):
    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
        r = []
        for item in row:
            if isinstance(item, text_type):
                item = item.encode('utf-8')
            r.append(item)
        row = r
    self.writer.writerow(row)
```

You can see that there is loop over the input `row`, hence it is expecting a list, but when you provide a string, it would simple loop over the string and consider it as a array of characters. Thats why the csv file would be something like this

```
2,0,1,8,-,0,8,-,2,7, ,1,5,:,2,1,:,4,9,",",5,5,2,3
2,0,1,8,-,0,8,-,2,7, ,1,5,:,2,1,:,5,2,",",3,5,1,2
2,0,1,8,-,0,8,-,2,7, ,1,5,:,2,1,:,5,6,",",3,3,8,3
```

Comment: I understand that the OP wants `delimiter = " "`.

Comment: OMG...It is so simple..! Thank you very much! May I know why I try to use the writerow(row) but it could not work?

Comment: @Winnie-c I have updated answer explaining why it won't work.

Comment: @argo If that is the case, I try to just revert the row into list type, but it could no work....

Comment: @JonClements Could you please recheck it, because zip is not giving the desired result.

Comment: @JonClements, I tried the "zip(x,y))" also. It also works! Thank you!

Comment: `writer.writerows(zip(x, y))` works for me... taking out the `for` loop

Comment: @JonClements the output is `"('2018-08-27 15:21:49', '5523')","('2018-08-27 15:21:52', '3512')","('2018-08-27 15:21:56', '3383')"`

Comment: @JonClements oops my bad. missed the `s` I was using `writer.writerow(zip(x, y))` instead of `writer.writerows(zip(x, y))`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
x=["2018-08-27 15:21:49","2018-08-27 15:21:52","2018-08-27 15:21:56"]
y=["5523","3512","3383"]
date_list = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'date': x,
     'num': y,
    })
date_list.to_csv('new.csv', sep='\t')
```

This can be helpful.